# How to validate forms in Magento 2 for custom module

Tags: forms, validation, magento2

I am creating simple custom module for user details in magento 2. It has form with three fileds. I want to validate the that data before I submit. How to achieve this in magento 2? Default magento validators are not working like data-validate={}... Do I have to add any additional js files for validation?

helloworld.phtml file

```
<form class="form create account form-create-account"   action="<?php echo $block->getFormAction() ?>" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data"  data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>
    <fieldset class="fieldset create account" data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>">
        <legend class="legend"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Customer Information') ?></span></legend><br>
        <div class="field required">
            <label for="email_address" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" id="email_address" value="" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true, 'validate-email':true}">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field required">
            <label for="First_Name" class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('FirstName') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="firstname"  id="first" value="" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Email') ?>" class="input-text" data-validate="{required:true}" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field required">
            <label  class="label"><span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('LastName') ?></span></label>
            <div class="control">
                <input type="text" name="lastname"  id="first" value="" title="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('LastName') ?>" class="input-text" >
            </div>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" class="action submit primary" <span><?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('Submit') ?></span></button>

</form>
```

Comment: your code looks perfect and checked its worked here , may be you have issue with your directory structure or layout issue , how you have load this template in your layout file ?

Comment: yeah...its working fine after i added this script in that above .phtml file .....<script type="text/x-magento-init">
    {
        "#custom-form": {
            "validation": {}
        }
    }
</script>

Comment: you don'need to add script in your phtml file just add this with your form - data-hasrequired="<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo __('* Required Fields') ?>"
      data-mage-init='{"validation":{}}'>

Comment: yes.Manthan Dave,you are correct .now its working without any addition script.I have recompiled the module by deleting total cache and generation files.

Comment: good to hear this @vijay b , Keep helping :)

Answer (score 4):

Below code for validation, for use below code you have to add `id` in your form and that `id` you need to use in below javascript code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
require([
    'jquery',
    'mage/mage'
], function($){

   var dataForm = $('#custom-form');
   dataForm.mage('validation', {});

});
</script>
```

The javascript library were validation is defined is

```
lib/web/mage/validation.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding validation, in Magento, I need a remote validation for form input element like entering username and validate this field before submitting the form to check this username exist or not? I have implemented this way ....is there any better suggestion?

[magento-jquery-remote-validation](http://www.ipragmatech.com/magento-jquery-remote-validation/)

Comment: That is good way I think so.check this core file MagentoRootDirectory/vendor/Magento/module-customer/view/frontend/template/form/register.phtml

Comment: Thanks a lot @vijayb